# Insert element into div with jQuery, append not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have the following code:

```
$('input[id$="txtTecnicas"]').bind('keypress', function (e) {
            //if user presses enter
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                //cancel asp.net postback
                e.preventDefault();

                //if value of textbox is not empty
                if ($(this).val() != "") {

                    //Save value into valueTec
                    var valueTec = $(this).val();
                    //Clear textbox value
                    $(this).val("");
                    //Create tag div to insert into div
                    var texthtml = '<span class="tag" title="' + valueTec + '">' + valueTec + ' <a>x</a><input type="hidden" value="1" name="tags"></span>';

                    //Append the new div inside tecTagHolder div
                    $('[id$="tecTagHolder"]').append(texthtml);
                }
            }
        });
```

However, it is not inserting the code into tecTagHolder div, and since it need to insert into tecTagHolder many divs, one each time user press enter, I cannot use `.html()` command but with append it doesn't append even a "Hello" string! what could it be wrong? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just select the tecTag like so:

```
$("#<%=tecTagHolder.ClientID %>").append(texthtml);
```

Comment: It's asp.net where the objects change names when objects has runat="server", using $("#tecTagHolder") just won't work.

Comment: are you getting an error? are you sure your selector is actually grabbing the DOM element you want? without your mark-up, it is difficult to see what may be wrong.

Comment: Wow! It worked perfectly! As soon i can mark your answer I'll do it! Thanks a lot!... How come my way didn't work?

Comment: This gets the ID of the rendered element on the page, the element you were targeting didn't exist.

Comment: so i'ts better use that way than mine. I'll keep that in mind! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
$('[id$="tecTagHolder"]').html( $('[id$="tecTagHolder"]').html() + texthtml );
```

But I'd recommend you generate that element like this:

```
var span = $('<span></span>').addClass('tag').attr('title', valueTec).text(valueTec);
var a = $('<a></a>').text('x');
.. and so on
```

Then construct the elements using like such:

```
span.append(a).append(input);
```

Then you can append the span into $('[id$="tecTagHolder"]').

Let me know if that helps :)